# Libguestfs copy_in, rsync_in operations are slow while copying/syncing large files

Tags: virtual-machine, disk

I am using [golang guestfs binding](https://libguestfs.org/guestfs-golang.3.html). I am exploring `Copy_in` and `Rsync_in` functions. While doing copy/sync of large files/dirs from local to image(qcow2 image), it takes a lot of time.
I went through the official [document](https://libguestfs.org/guestfs.3.html#uploading) and [this](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/tip-uploading-and-downloading/) and it recommends to create the iso and attach the created iso as an extra disk. This really improves the performance as I don't need to do the `Copy_in` or `Rsync_in`. I can use the `cp-a` or `cp-r`(it will be like copying locally from mounted iso to mounted qcow2)

But again there is an overhead of creating iso. `genisoimage`/`mkisofs` takes lot of time(approx 6 mins for 10Gi data with around 2 cpus and 3 Gi memory).

Is there any way to improve the Copy_in/Rsync_in performance? or is there any way to make the iso creation process faster?